# Wpf custom control for cinema, stadium or hall

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a task to create in wpf control as close as possible to this one 
[from the link (please click "Select Tickets" tab to see a control)](https://www.payservices.com/ticketing.php?event=E805F9CF3E681413A856)

I'd like to ask for any advise where to start from?
Should I use *canvas*? If It's not a canvas, How to use zoom?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many answers for this question. At first sight, I would try to follow the next steps :

1. Create a control for the dots -> A circle (`Path`) which has a dependency property for its color.
2. Create a dynamic `Grid` with the number of columns and rows that you want and insert in every cell the control that you`ve created in the first step with the right fill color.
3. The zoom should be achieved by adjusting the number of columns and rows in your dynamic grid.If the number of columns it is reduced, the custom control will be stretched and will appear as a zoomed region.
4. Keep in mind that you have to use ObservableCollections and TwoWay Bindings in order to get the updates on the UI.

Hope it helps! Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I met my client, he said It's ok to use only schemes using grid. That's mean your question is very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) to enable the control to size to the available space.

@Dragosh's answer is a good option. But there are often seating layouts that are not a grid. I would recommend creating a custom ItemsControl that binds to a collection of 'Seats' that have properties outlining their Section, Row, etc. and location. That way you can create a DataTemplate and ItemStyle that places the seat control at the correct location.